# Redirect Main URL to HTTPS, All Subdomains to HTTP but keep existing rules

Tags: php, .htaccess

Currently working on something and need assistance with my htaccess file.

I have it set up right now and it's working how I want it where it will remove the trailing slash, and remove .php so it looks like a directory. It also will redirect bar.example.com to a file example.com/thing?foo=bar

I want to make use of the SSL certificate I purchased and force HTTPS on any main domain pages, but force HTTP when visiting the subdomain because my certificate is not a wildcard.

Any help is appreciated, what I currently have is posted below.

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).example.com
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ http://example.com/thing?foo=%1 [P,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Redirect your existing conditions directly to https:// and then add a new rule that checks for `%{HTTPS}`. See the [Apache docs](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS) for more information.

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).example.com
# CHANGE: Redirect your subdomains directly to the secure target URL
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ https://example.com/thing?foo=%1 [P,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# CHANGE: same goes for the folders
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]

# NEW: Redirect everything else that comes in on `http://www.`
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: So, this did not force example.com to https://example.com. And, it changed my URL from bar.examle.com to example.com/thing?foo=bar and it shows the full URL rather than bar.example.com

Comment: The redirect from `http://www.example.com` to `https://www.example.com` should work. If you want to match `http://example.com`, omit the `www\.` or make it optional in the RegEx `^(www\.)?example\.com`. But as you are checking for it in your first rule, I thought that's how you are set up. "it changed my URL from bar.examle.com to example.com/thing?foo=bar " That's what your 2nd rule does. Is that not the expected behavior?

Comment: No, it's supposed to keep the URL but proxy the page which it was and still is doing, but now it shows the ugly URL.

Comment: I used your code and it works great, I had to change one line otherwise it kept giving 500 internal server error.

    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ https://example.com/thing?foo=%1 [P,L]

Had to be without the https.

Comment: @RyanNacker if this answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it and therefore mark this question as answered.